# get dictionary from input

Tags: python, dictionary

trying to get a dictionary from user input, there will be multiple dictionary's to reference from, user is expected to input "A1" when asked, and expected to "get something 1" as a result, but this gives "string indicies must be integers". any help is appreciated.

```py
A = {
    "A1": "something1",
    "A2": "something2",
}
B = {
    "B1": "somethingelse1",
    "B2": "somethingelse2",
}
    
user_error = input("what is your error? ").upper()
first_half = user_error[0]
print(first_half[user_error])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of confusion going on in your post, so I cleaned it up a little and created a solution for you:

```py
A = {
    "A1": "something1",
    "A2": "something2",
}
B = {
    "B1": "somethingelse1",
    "B2": "somethingelse2",
}

user_error = input("what is your error? ").upper()
dict_name = user_error[0]

selected_dict = locals()[dict_name]

print(selected_dict[user_error])
```

Unfortunately, I don't see a simpler way than to use `locals`, which you are probably the least familiar with. But more importantly in order to undertand the rest of the solution in particular, I strongly recommend to read up on the basics of Python, e.g. [here](https://realpython.com/python-first-steps/).

Answer (score 0):

Two input is necessary for this. Example code:

```
A = {
"A1" : "something1",
"A2" : "something2"
}
B = {
    "B1" : "somethingelse1",
    "B2" : "somethingelse2"
}
which_dict = input("what is your choice? ").upper()
selected = {}
if which_dict == "A": selected = A
else: selected = B
user_error = input("what is your error? ").upper()
first_half = selected[user_error]
print(first_half)
```